# How can I implement infinite scrolling on a table using react-virualised?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

**I have been struggling with react-virtualised docs** They have full-featured example tables.
All I want is simple infinite scrolling for my table. Please if anyone can help.
I just want to render my content when it's visible on the screen.
**NOTE: I am not pulling the data from any API I have static data(an array of objects) saved into my local folder.**
Please see a screenshot of my app below.
[image]

Below is my code.

```
const renderRows = items.map((data, index) => {
    return (
      <tr
        className="table__row"
        key={data.id}
        onClick={() => onRowClick(data.id)}
      >
        <td style={{ marginRight: '2px' }}>
          <img
            onClick={(e) => {
              toggleStarSelect(e, data.id);
            }}
            src={Star}
            className="star"
            alt="star"
            style={{ padding: '2px' }}
          />

          {data['#']}
        </td>
        <td>
          <ImageLoadHandler
            isloaded={isloaded}
            handleImage={handleImage}
            data={data}
          />

          <span style={{ padding: '10px' }}>{data.Name}</span>
          <span
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
              opacity: '0.5',
              fontSize: '13px',
            }}
          >
            {data.Symbol}
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>{data.Price}</td>
        <td>{data['1h']}</td>
        <td className={data['24h'] > 0 ? 'green' : 'red'}>
          {data['24h'] > 0 ? (
            <img className="arrowicon" src={SortUpGreen} alt="sort-up-green" />
          ) : (
            <img className="arrowicon" src={SortDownRed} alt="sort-down-red" />
          )}
          {data['24h']}%
        </td>
        <td>{data['7d']}</td>
        <td>{data['Mkt Cap']}</td>
        <td>{data['24h Vol']}</td>
        <td style={{ padding: '0', paddingRight: '8px' }}>
          <Suspense fallback={<div className="loading">loading...</div>}>
            <Graph data={data} idx={index} />
          </Suspense>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <header>
        <Header />
      </header>
      <table className="app__table">
        <thead className="app__tablehead">
          <tr>
            <th
              onClick={() => requestSort('#')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('#')} //returns ascending or descending
            >
              #
            </th>
            <th
              onClick={() => requestSort('Name')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('Name')}
            >
              Coin
            </th>
            <th
              onClick={() => requestSort('Price')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('Price')}
            >
              Price
            </th>
            <th
              onClick={() => requestSort('1h')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('1h')}
            >
              1h
            </th>
            <th
              onClick={() => requestSort('24h')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('24h')}
            >
              24h
            </th>
            <th
              onClick={() => requestSort('7d')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('7d')}
            >
              7d
            </th>
            <th
              onClick={() => requestSort('Mkt Cap')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('Mkt Cap')}
            >
              Mkt Cap
            </th>
            <th
              onClick={() => requestSort('24h Vol')}
              className={getClassNamesFor('24h Vol')}
            >
              24h Vol
            </th>
            <th className="nohover">Last 7 days</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{renderRows}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Right now you render all rows at once? I mean you try to render 10 by 10 for example?

Comment: I render all row at once. I want to render only rows that are visible on the screen and as we scroll render them too.

Comment: HI, @Kostas did you found any solution as to why my code didn't work? [Here is my code](https://pastebin.com/1xUGHPvB) which I just converted from a working class-based component to a functional-based component. [the code you sent](https://repl.it/@masterakos/Create-React-App#src/App.js)

Comment: Hi @Tarun Singh, I made a question for this you can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625488/state-updates-only-once-inside-a-divs-scroll-event-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example of infinite scroll on a table element. Also a working a [repl](https://repl.it/@masterakos/Create-React-App).

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  let items = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    items.push({
      key: 'foo' + i,
      value: 'bar' + i,
    });
  }

  let dataTable = React.createRef();
  
  const [list, setList] = useState({
    itemsDisplayed: 20,
    data: items.slice(0, 20),
  });

  let onScroll = () => {
    let tableEl = dataTable.current;
    if (tableEl.scrollTop === (tableEl.scrollHeight - tableEl.offsetHeight)) {
      if (list.itemsDisplayed + 10 <= items.length) {
        setList({
          itemsDisplayed: list.itemsDisplayed + 10,
          data: items.slice(0, list.itemsDisplayed + 10),
        });
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table id="data-table" ref={dataTable} onScroll={onScroll}>
        <tbody>
          {list.data.map((item) => {
            return (
              <tr key={item.key}>
                {item.value}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also to mention, the problem of scrolling firing only once solved by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625488/state-updates-only-once-inside-a-divs-scroll-event-handler/65625700#65625700). The point is to use React's built-in onScroll event.