# State updates only once inside a div's scroll event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my example there is a scrollable div and I try to update the state (just a counter) inside onscroll event of this div. What happens is it updates only once (the first time). [This is working repl](https://repl.it/@masterakos/PowderblueLovableLocus#src/App.js) of my example.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {

  let divRef = React.createRef();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    count: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    divRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      setState({
        count: state.count + 1, // this happens only once
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{position: 'fixed', top: '0'}}>{state.count}</div>
      <div style={{height: '100px', overflow: 'auto'}} ref={divRef}>
        <div style={{height: '1000px'}}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update state on scroll then you can use `onScroll` provided by React.

[Repl-demo](https://repl.it/@GermaVinsmoke/PowderblueLovableLocus-1#src/App.js)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    setCount(p => p + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{position: 'fixed', top: '0'}}>{count}</div>
      <div style={{height: '100px', overflow: 'auto'}} onScroll={handleScroll}>
        <div style={{height: '1000px'}}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```